# Which technologies should I use to query a SQL Database with Javascript in local?

Tags: javascript, html, localhost

I have a basic knowledge of SQL and a basic knowledge of JS, mostly from school. I'm looking forward a way to create a HTML/CSS/JS webpage in local to query (select/insert/update) a SQL Database, but I saw a lot of different ways to do it. I need some help to get through the vastity of all those info. Which are the easiest ways to achieve my goal and which are the most up-to-date ones today?

Answer (score 1):

Try node.js is you prefer JS on server. It has loads of libraries allowing connections to pretty much all databases out there.
There are very helpful tutorials on youtube showing how to start. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGZX_SA7lYg) is one of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The link you send me is perfect for what I need. It's not easy to walk through all these different info and technologies. Thanks again from a noob.